# Defining categories in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I'm trying to define verified categories internal to Idris types, but my approach doesn't type check.

```
class Cat ob (mor : ob -> ob -> Type) where 
  comp  : {a : ob} -> {b : ob} -> {c : ob} -> mor a b -> mor b c -> mor a c
  unit   : (a : ob) -> mor a a
  l     : {a,b : ob} -> {f : mor a b} -> (comp (unit a) f) = f
```

`ob` is the type of objects, `mor a b` is the type of morphisms from `a` to `b`.
There are the right unit and associativity laws still to come, but already my definition for `l` doesn't work. It says:

```
 When elaborating type of constructor of Main.Cat:
 When elaborating an application of comp:
         Can't unify
                 mor a13 b14 (Type of f)
         with
                 mor b14 c (Expected type)
```

I find that confusing. `unit a` has type `mor a a`, `f` has type `mor a b`, why doesn't `comp (unit a) f` have type `mor a b` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only works if I explicitly give the implicit parameters:

```
class Cat ob (mor : ob -> ob -> Type) where
  comp  : {a : ob} -> {b : ob} -> {c : ob} -> mor a b -> mor b c -> mor a c
  unit  : (a : ob) -> mor a a
  l     : {a,b : ob} -> {f : mor a b} -> (comp {a=a} {b=a} {c=b} (unit a) f) = f
```

Edwin Brady points out in [this issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2249), why. The reason is that there is no restriction on `mor a b` and `mor b c` being the actually same type. For example, `mor` could be a constant function. In that cases, the type checker can't infer `a` and `b` just from `mor a b`, which leads to the error message.

If one had the restriction that `mor` be an injective function (as will probably be done for class arguments in the future), it would be possible to infer `a` and `b` and no longer necessary to give the arguments implicitly.

Comment: You should probably file an issue on Github. Sometimes, these things are bugs.

Comment: @dfeuer, thanks for encouraging me. I indeed did that and posted Edwin's answer here.